# Azure Function with EventGridTrigger prevents FunctionsStartup class's Configure method from running

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

I'm trying to have a function that has its dependencies injected as outlined in documentation, [Use dependency injection in .NET Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection). My Startup class is defined as:

```csharp
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

    [assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyFunctions.Startup))]

    namespace MyFunctions{    
      public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
      {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
          builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
        }
      }
    }
```

I set a breakpoint on the `builder.Services.AddHttpClient()` statement to ensure the DI is configured.
Then I define my function using a `HttpTrigger`:

```csharp
    using System;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
    using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

    namespace MyFunctions
    {
        public class ChangeProducer
        {
            private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

            public ChangeProducer(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
            {
                _httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
            }

            [FunctionName("ChangeProducer")]
            public void Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "Reservation")]HttpRequest request, ILogger log)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("foo");
            }
        }
    }
```

When I run this from Visual Studio I hit the breakpoint in `Startup.Configure`. **Wonderful!**

Then I change my function to use an `EventGridTrigger`:

```csharp
    using System;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
    using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

    namespace MyFunctions
    {
        public class ChangeProducer
        {
            private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

            public ChangeProducer(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
            {
                _httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
            }

            [FunctionName("ChangeProducer")]
            public void Run([EventGridTrigger]EventGridEvent eventGridEvent, ILogger log)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("foo");
            }
        }
    }
```

Once that change is made, and no other change, I ***don't hit*** the breakpoint in `Startup.Configure`. Additionally, I know the DI is failing because when I try to invoke the function I get an error message that reads:

```
    Executed 'ChangeProducer' (Failed, Id=06ae8b88-07c4-4150-91e5-8b88400aed72)
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Net.Http.IHttpClientFactory' while attempting to activate 'MyFunctions.ChangeProducer'.
```

Is there a known issue? I can't figure this out. The only difference is the trigger type.

### Update 2019-06-24 - It's just the dependency injection

I want to be clear the issue is dependency injection isn't working, there isn't an issue with the `EventGridTrigger` when the dependency on `HttpClient` is not injected. Change the constructor to the following and the function works fine when triggered by the `EventGridTrigger`:

```csharp
    public ChangeProducer()
    {
        _httpClient = new HttpClient();
    }
```

Comment: How are you testing the EventGrid triggered function?

Comment: Invoking the test URL via Postman http://localhost:7071/runtime/webhooks/EventGrid?functionName={functionname}

Comment: Strange. Did you create the function from the EventGrid template?

Comment: Not sure - someone else on the team initially created this function and added a comment with the URL to test with (he's out today). FWIW it's just the dependency injection that seems to suffer. When I comment the constructor documented above and use a default constructor that sets `_httpClient = new HttpClient();` the function works fine via the `EventGridTrigger`. I'll update the post with that info for clarity.

Comment: chris, I've confirmed the function was created via the EventGrid template.

Comment: Ah okay. I'd recommend recreating it again via the template and see if that works? Maybe something has somehow got messed up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the dependency injection issue after creating a new function app and slowly building it out and comparing to the project that was experiencing the problem. The `host.json` file contained a property named `extensionBundle`. Once I removed that the dependency injection started working again. The entire property looks like this:

```json
    "extensionBundle": {
        "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
        "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully tested with the following packages and Visual Studio 2019, version 16.1.3.

[image]

The following screen snippets show the debugging steps:

1. On the Start-up

[image]

2. Invoking a function by POST

   http://localhost:7071/runtime/webhooks/EventGrid?functionName=Function1

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the information, Roman. You list a few of NuGet packages I didn't have installed; `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http`, `Microsoft.Extensions.Http`, and `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` - so I installed those (same versions you listed). Unfortunately, the dependency injection is still failing with the same error `Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Net.Http.IHttpClientFactory'...`. Next step is to start with fresh solution and see if I can get what you've provided to work locally.